# DropDownList Items.FindByText is inserting: &quot; Selected=&quot;True

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET (VB) drop down list which is listing countries for the user to select on a form.

Code in front:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCountry" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcecountryList" DataTextField="country_name_long" DataValueField="country_name_short">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

FYI, both `country_name_long` and `country_name_short` contain the same values/text in this database.

In the code behind I am selecting 'United Kingdom' as the default Selected item:

```
DropDownListCountry.DataBind()
DropDownListCountry.Items.FindByText("United Kingdom").Selected = True
```

I also tried using this, but it produced the same result:

```
DropDownListCountry.DataBind()
DropDownListCountry.SelectedIndex = DropDownListCountry.Items.IndexOf(DropDownListCountry.Items.FindByText("United Kingdom"))
```

This code appears to be inserting something very wrong when I then view the source of the end result HTML:

```
<option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
<option value="United Arab Erimates">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option selected="selected" value="United Kingdom&quot; Selected=&quot;True">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
<option value="Uraguay">Uruguay</option>
```

You'll see from the United Kingdom line that some HTML appears to have been generated on the fly.

Expected result:

```
    <option selected="selected" value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
```

Actual result:

```
    <option selected="selected" value="United Kingdom&quot; Selected=&quot;True">United Kingdom</option>
```

What's wrong/broken/faulty here?

Comment: Two questions, more like a sanity checks. 1. What happens if you do not mark any item as selected? 2. Is exactly same thing happening if you mark other country as selected?

Comment: Ahhh FFS.  Mate, you nailed it. Sure enough, not a single other country was affected by this issue. Would you believe that the DB row for United Kingdom actually contains the corrupt HTML!!!!  Thank you my friend!

Comment: So embarrassing :(   What's the correct way for me to close/ignore this stackoverflow issue?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `.SelectedIndex` try:

```
    DropDownListCountry.SelectedValue = DropDownListCountry.Items(
DropDownListCountry.Items.FindByText("United Kingdom"))
```

Comment: I'm afraid that throws an error of:   Value of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' cannot be converted to 'Integer'

Comment: @Rich Are you certain that you removed the call to `.IndexOf`?

Comment: Yes sir, completely - I commented out my line and copied and pasted your line in its entirety - http://pasteboard.co/8EfgMs7D0.png

Comment: I apologise for wasting your time mate - please see comments above